# Get data ready for IFFT

Tags: matlab, time-frequency, ifft

I am having troubles applying the IFFT function to some data I have. I already had a look here [Complex conjugate and IFFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/282/complex-conjugate-and-ifft) and here [What assumptions should be used to invert spectrum into time domain data?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13899/what-assumptions-should-be-used-to-invert-spectrum-into-time-domain-data) but it still does not work.

This is the code:

```
% amplitude: data related to the signal amplitude
% phase: data related to the signal phase
% freq: frequencies (from 5 to 100 Hz)

response = complex(amplitude,phase);

NFFT = length(response); % odd number
symmetric = zeros(NFFT,1); 

for i = 1:NFFT
symmetric(i) = conj(response(mod(NFFT-i+1,NFFT)+1));
end

response_tot = [response; symmetric];

% Plot simmetry
response_tot = fftshift(response_tot);
f_plot = 100*(-NFFT:(NFFT-1))/NFFT;
figure()
plot(f_plot,response_tot)

% Time signal
time_sig = ifft(ifftshift(response_tot));

fs = 2*max_f; % twice the max frequency in the signal
t_plot = 0:1/fs:NFFT/fs; % time vector to plot the time response

figure()
plot(t_plot,time_sig(1:NFFT+1))
```

Is this the right way to prepare the data for the ifft?

Because the output does not look right to me.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the function `complex`. It takes its first argument as real and its second argument as imaginary part of the complex number it returns. What you want is `response = amplitude .* exp(1i*phase)`

Comment: That part gave me some problems actually. I have the original plot of the frequency response and the one calculated using `complex` is equal to the orginal one, whereas if I use `amplitude .* exp(1i*phase)` I get a negative peak that should not be there.

Comment: I was just thinking...is there any difference in calculating the symmetric part of the vector if N is odd or even?

Answer (score 1):

The first component of the FFT is the DC component. The other `NFFT-1` should be symmetric.
If `NFFT` is even, that means that

```
response(NFFT/2-k)=conj(response(NFFT/2+k))
```

for $k=1,\ldots,NFFT/2-1$ and response(NFFT/2) is arbitrary.
If `NFFT` is odd then

```
response((NFFT+1)/2-k)=conj(response((NFFT+1)/2+k+1))
```

for $k=0,\ldots,(NFFT-1)/2-1$.

However, MATLAB allows you to ignore all that by using the `'symmetric'` argument of ifft:

```
response_tot = [response; zeros(NFFT-1,1)]; % assuming NFFT is odd
time_sig = ifft(response_tot,'symmetric');
```